# Linq Join Keeping All Fields From One Side w/o Explicit Listing

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

My code requires several inner join of two db sets. One set is quite large (~20 columns) and all fields are relevant. Is there a way to output all fields w/o explicitly listing them?

Simplified version of my code (`db` is my context):

```
var x = db.BigFact
        .join(db.Lookup1, l => l.Lookup1Id, r => r.Lookup1Id
             (l, r) => new {l.Col1, l.Col2 … l.Col20, r.OneName}
         )
```

The `...` represent listing of all fields from the left side. Writing them repeatedly is tedious, especially given there is strongly typed class representing "BigFact".

I'm looking for something like SQL's syntax:

```
SELECT l.*, r.OneName
FROM BigFact as l
JOIN Lookup1 as r
ON   l.Lookup1Id = r.Lookup1Id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var x = db.BigFact
    .join(db.Lookup1, l => l.Lookup1Id, r => r.Lookup1Id
         (l, r) => new { Left = l, r.OneName}
     )
```

Comment: and @%ce%a9megaman, your solutions show all the left objects encapsulate the left objects in one class (e.g. Michael's `Left` thus the x structure is `{Left, OneName}` which requires use `..x.Left.Col14..`). Is there a method/function that would extract the actual fields (e.g. like map or _ in Scala)?

Answer (score 1):

> output all fields w/o explicitly listing them?

Just put in the original item such as `FullItem` shown below.

```
(l, r) => new {l.Col1, l.Col2, FullItem = l, r.OneName}
```

That creates a new entity with fields of `Col1`, `Col2`, `OneName` and `FullItem`. Dereference items from `FullItem` like `FullItem.Col3` and even `FullItem.Col1`.